# Best choice for Java and Wcf interoperability in jBPM (jBoss)

Tags: wcf, soap, jboss, jbpm

I'm using the workflow engine jBPM which runs in jBoss.

During the workflow I'll need to call methods implemented in .Net WCF but obviously jBPM runs in Java.

Therefore I'd like to know, considering already have jBoss running, which is the best way to communicate with WCF exposed services using Java.

Edit: What I had in mind was implementing the java part in Glassfish as a web service but I don't know if that's the best choice. WCF is quite simple as a SOAP solution and I wanted something similar in java

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried?

Comment: What I had in mind was implementing the java part in Glassfish as a web service but I don't know if that's the best choice. WCF is quite simple as a SOAP solution and I wanted something similar in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create simple clients from your WCF services using the JAX-WS client libraries and consume your services from jBPM.
Cheers